# Best practice to move data from an older object to a new object design

Tags: java, mysql, database, oop, refactoring

I picked up on an older project, that never used objects well.
Say for example the object is Driver.

instead of having fields initialized like

```
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private Date dateOfBirth;
```

The code was designed to use a map of strings to store everything so...

```
protected Map<String, String> data;
```

So obviously casting strings to different data types is a hassle to do every time.

All the data is stored inside Blobs inside MySQL, so backfilling it seems to be the only solution. As in call all the driver objects that are stored and create a method that maps the data to the fields and then restore the objects.

Im not really sure what the best practice here would be, hoping you guys could shed some light on an object refactor.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean all the project? For the database you could rename the old table, recreate it and then "recover" all the data using `INSERT INTO Driver SELECT FROM Driver_Old`. For the application, what's the language? Will you use the same in this new version?

Comment: The ony "best practice" here is to roll the sleeves up and do the dirty job.

Comment: Yeah the entire project. The application is in Java, using MySQL as the database, and struts2, jsps & servlets for the frontend. @MiguelKVidal

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](/help)

, in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic). This question should better be asked at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com or https://codereview.stackexchange.com but even there it would need more details to give a descend answer.  Please delete this question if you move to one of the other sites.

Comment: @lexicore exactly what i was thinking, but was hoping i didnt have to do. The project was poorly designed, and im trying to clean it all up before adding things to a broken structure.

Comment: @ThePirateBae Sometimes it is easier to make a new child rather than to wash up the dirty one.

Comment: @ThePirateBae what about start a new project with a clean code base, using the correct data structures. Then slowly you will be able to migrate the bussiness logic from the old project to the new one, using everything you want.

Comment: @MiguelKVidal they have about 30k+ objects stored the old way. Just came on to the job, and the code base is horrific. But its a job that i need at this moment in time. Im not sure if starting from a clean code base is an option at this point..

Comment: Update the database is simpler, since you can do with queries. But will need a data analysis before. The code is another thing. What's easier for you: rewrite from scratch or update everything small bits at a time?

Comment: @MiguelKVidal i cant even update the database via queries (was my initial thought) because eveything is stored as serialized data in blobs. There are only primary keys attached to the blobs with reference tables. So i guess update small bits at a time. Also thanks for responding.

Comment: @ThePirateBae as I said, you will need to analyze the database and verify what's possible here. What's the structure used on those blob columns? You could write text there. If you can read it, you could use it to do a new insert.

Comment: @MiguelKVidal true, you're 100% correct. Ill just dig into the blobs and see if i can do inserts on those fields to fix them. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the database perspective, you would need to analyze the data you have and recreate the tables. (Maybe even recreate the DB?)

If you have a way to read the data on the old tables, ou could do something like this:

1. Rename table `Driver` to `Driver_Old`
2. Create a new `Driver` table with the new structure
3. Insert all the data from the old table to the new one, using something like `INSERT INTO Driver SELECT * FROM Driver_Old`

But for the codebase you have another problem.
From there, I can see 2 different approaches:

A - Create a new project, from scratch, and slowly migrate the business logic.

B - Update the project codebase to match your new database schema and then adjust everything that needs some adjustment.

What's the better? Hard to say.

One would need to analyze both the database and the code you have.

If it's production database, then the best practice would be to do it in a development environment.

Comment: You're the man. Thank you for the help.